# Embedded Task Form reference through a proxy server

Tags: forms, proxy, camunda

I have a Camunda bpm tomcat 7.3 instance launch through a proxy server.

In my process, i have a user task configured with an embedded form task.

My problem is that the reference "Form Key" to embedded:app:forms/myform.html is not proxify and we cannot proxify this.

I want to know if there is a different way to make a ref. to the embedded form or can i set the "embedded:app:" variable ?

The error display on camunda tasklist when trying to get the form:

```
Form failure: cannot GET /core_ors_bpm_tps2mdmbygis-dataflow-process-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT/forms/validatePayloadForm.html?noCache=1442311746289 (403)
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I configured the FormKey to `embedded:myForm.html` and I moved the html form in

`CAMUNDA_TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/camunda/app/tasklist/default/`

Regards